# Dealing with an empty list in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, list, template-engine, mustache

I'm using mustache.js to render a template in javascript. I'd like to check if a list is empty or not to hide the `<h2>` tag in the following example. Is this possible or is mustache.js too logic-less?

This is the template:

```
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    {{name}}
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
```

and this is the data:

```
{
  "persons":[
    {"name": "max"},
    {"name": "tom"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The "data" is not valid JSON.

Comment: Also, you may want to think about switching from mustache to [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), which can much more gracefully (dare I say it?) _handle_ cases like this one. This isn't the first time that someone asked for (and was denied) and empty-list test in mustache: https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/issues/47.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I'm punishing you for not making your comment an answer (which I would happily have voted up) by posting it as an answer myself and stealing your yummy karma points.

Comment: @superjoe30 `*shrug*`, enjoy :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To keep your template logic-less, you can make this check before rendering the template:

```
// assuming you get the JSON converted into an object
var data = {
    persons: [
        {name: "max"}
      , {name: "tom"}
    ]
};
data.hasPersons = (data.persons.length > 0);
```

Then your template will look like this:

```
<h2>Persons:</h2>
{{#hasPersons}}
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
{{/hasPersons}}
```

Comment: As much as this is a correct answer, I think having to use this kind of approach is a sign of a real weakness in Mustache syntax.  It's maybe OK as long as the front end (template) developer has access to the back end (data source) code, but if the two are separate or the front end dev is more of a HTML slinger than coder, it's going to get pretty unworkable.

Comment: @TimHolt well, I definitely get your point. There are advantages though. Let's assume that you want to unit-test this part of your app. With a logic-less templating engine, I'm content with only unit-testing the data (before it is fed to Mustache) and not having to do string-comparing tests on the resulting html. Now, if my template would have logic (even as simple as checking .length > 0) I'd feel the need to unit-test that logic, and would thus be forced to either do string-comparison or something like selenium/doh robot. So, that's the trade-off in my opinion.

Comment: The purpose of templating is to separate the View from the Models and Controllers. This solution is basically moving View meta-information into the Controller. The fact that Mustache makes you do these things defeats its own purpose. Templates shouldn't be logicless (an if-statement is also logic so it isn't logicless anyway), but templates should contain view-logic and no application-logic.

Answer (score 49):

After struggling for half a day with this problem, I've finally found an easy solution!

Don't check for the list, but check if its first item is not empty!

Template:

```
{{#persons.0}}
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
{{/persons.0}}
{{^persons.0}}No persons{{/persons.0}}
```

Data:

```
{
  "persons":[
    {"name": "max"},
    {"name": "tom"}
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  <li>max</li>
  <li>tom</li>
</ul>
```

Data:

```
{
  "persons": []
}
```

Output:

```
"No Persons"
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted! It is generic, mustache-only solution that does not assume javascript

Comment: It didn't work for me.  I'm using Mustashe.java.  This lack of a conditional on empty is a deal-breaker for me.  Back to FreeMarker...

Comment: This works. Just like to add, for an unnamed list, which is looped through using {{#.}} then {{^.}}No Persons{{/.}} can be used.

Answer (score 47):

You could use persons.length. If it is a truthy value (i.e. greater than 0) then the block will be rendered.

```
{{#persons.length}}
<h2>Persons:</h2>
<ul>
  {{#persons}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/persons}}
</ul>
{{/persons.length}}
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you're rendering server side (outside javascript)

Comment: @iwein: the question *was* tagged `javascript` after all, and it works in node, too :) @Qazzian: +1, a clean way of avoiding mustache lambdas!

Comment: @o.v. I gave this answer an upvote, don't worry. The additional info in the comment would have been helpful to me however.

Comment: For mustache.java, you can use `{{^people.isEmpty}}`

Comment: +1 for `{{^people.isEmpty}}`, just verified this works.

Comment: Thank you Qazzian for the answer and @JoshUnger for the java version!

Comment: So this is my best answer ever on SO and it still gets a lot of attention. It is only intended for javascript as the truthy/falsey nature of array.length only works in type week scripting languages. I've been a JS developer most of my career so I don't really know how best to do this in Java or other server-side languages. TBH, I'm surprised people still use mustache with the advent of react, angular and vue.

Answer (score 7):

Use [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) instead. It's a superset of Mustache which gives you that little bit more power that you need. The mustache community asked for this feature but the maintainer [refuses to put it in](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/issues/47).

Answer (score 5):

In javascript you can check with `{{#names.length}}{{/names.length}}` or with `{{#names.0}}`

If you're outside of javascript (e.g. in pystache or Scalate), you're out of luck. The only solution then is to introduce a separate boolean, or nest your array in an object which you avoid entirely if you have an empty array, like maxbeatty suggested.

Comment: So I understand why this works in JavaScript, is it because everything is an object, including the array, so you can use the object's methods to inspect it. But in other languages a string is a string, and an array is an array, and they do not have object methods to interrogate? Mustache does not know nor care that these are object methods - the underlying language just provides what makes sense. Is that about right? I'm trying to understand what features are mustache, and what are not, and why.